# Is there any use to create index on all the table columns in oracle?

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle11gr2

In our one of production database, we have 4 column table and there are no PK,UK constraints on it. only one notnull constraint on one column. The inserts are slow on this table and when I checked the indexes , there is one index which is built on all columns.

It is a normal table and not IOT. I really don't see a need of all column index, but wondering why the developers has created it?

Appreciate your thoughts?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414221/oracle-insert-performance-on-indexed-tables

Comment: Maybe 'cause there's a query that uses it? Can you ask the other developers/search for queries that use this table? You can't remove the index without checking. If inserts are slow I'd also look at whether you're doing them row-by-row or in bulk.

Comment: Perhaps the developer was not aware of the possibility to create Index-Organized-Tables, or he was just to lazy to read the documentation how to create them.

Answer (score 2):

It might be usefull, i.e. if you (mainly) query all columns oracle doesn't have to access the table at all, but can get all the data from the index. Though inserts take longer because a larger index has to be maintained by the dbms everytime.

Comment: So in the case where query accesses the all columns of table, it can fetch from the table it self instead from index? (it is the table where frequent inserts/delete are happening). Do you really see a need of all column index even when query accesses all columns? How much benefit it is?

Comment: It is the other way round, in that case data comes directly from the index and the table is not accessed ( http://www.orafaq.com/node/1403 ). You'll have to measure the benefit on your system, there's allways a trade-off between faster select and faster update/insert using indexes which cannot be answered in general.

Answer (score 1):

One case where it could be useful is,

Say for example, you are trying to check the existence of records in this table and for that you have to have joins on all four columns. So in such a case if you have written a correlated query like below,

```
SELECT <something>
FROM table_1 t1
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM table_t2 t2 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t1.c2=t2.c2 and t1.c3=t2.c3 and t1.c4=t2.c4)
```

Apart from above case, it looks an error to me from developer's side.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are good to better query optimization but causes slow updates/inserts because the indexes needs to be updated at each modification.

If these tables first use is querying and inserts happens only in a specific periods like a batch at the beginning or the end of the day only, then you can remove the indexes before updating tables and then restore them.

In addition, all the queries all these tables need to be analysed to see which indexes are useful and which are not?

Anyway, You need to ask developers before removing these indexes.